# Java Framework for RDF version tracking

Tags: java, versioning, rdf

I'm looking for a java framework for handling RDF data in a graph database. The main purpose is to manage several versions of a RDF graph and all versions must be accessible all the time. So version tracking is an important feature I need. Is there any tool that supports this out of the box without to develop it from scratch?

The only tool I found related to this topic is `OpenAnzo`, but the website is no longer available.

To add a timestamp to the nodes should not be the problem, but also an easy access via `SPARQL` or another query language should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [Alibaba Auditing Repository](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/alibaba/2.0-rc5/alibaba-repository-auditing/index.html) and [Auditing SAIL](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/alibaba/2.0-rc5/alibaba-sail-auditing/index.html), which are [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/) extensions for RDF data change tracking and provenance (disclosure: I'm on the Sesame development team).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing database solutions which provide versioning out of the box.  Your best bet is to work on a custom scheme for your application over an existing database.  For example, you could put different versions of the data into named graphs and use those as the versioning structure, then using from/from named in your query be able to query some or all different versions of your data.  You could also try and works something up with reification which would give similar results.